# Unable to copy files using Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am unable to copy files using Shell script. I validated in shellcheck.net no issues found in syntax.

It showing error as file not fount but I am using exact file name.

Below is my Shell script.

```
#! /bin/bash
export SOURCE_PATH="/home/la1122/export"
export SOURCE_TARGET="/home/la1122/export/backup"
FILE="*.dat"
cd $SOURCE_PATH
echo "Current location: $(pwd)"
cp "$FILE" "$SOURCE_TARGET"
```

Comment: When a question is closed, you can still [edit] it, and should do so rather than asking a new one.

Comment: That said -- what exactly is the error message this time? (Last time the error you had was caused by your script being saved with DOS newlines).

Comment: ..._oh_. `"$FILE"`. That doesn't work, because the glob isn't expanded. (It's a new/different problem, because you weren't quoting `$FILE` in the last question).

Comment: Use `files=( *.dat )`, and then `cp "${files[@]}" "$SOURCE_TARGET"`

Comment: ...mind, you shouldn't be using all-caps names for your own variables at all (and you also shouldn't be `export`ing variables without a good reason to do so).

Comment: Also, use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)` -- the latter is much slower, because it makes a whole new copy of your shell to run the `pwd` command in.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I am new to this Shell script so pls excuse me for dumb mistakes. 

I did tried as you said. 

#! /bin/bash
export SOURCE_PATH="/home/la1122/export"
export SOURCE_TARGET="/home/la1122/export/backup"
file=(*.dat)
echo "Locatio: $PWD"
cp "${file[@]}" "$SOURCE_TARGET

Comment: I am still getting error says cp: cannot stat a(*.dat)\ra: No such file or directory

Comment: Go ahead and [edit] the question with the new code and the error (it's frowned on to do that if an answer was added with "Add an Answer" and an edit would make it incorrect, but these are all just comments so you don't need to worry about that)

Comment: BTW, maybe you want `file=( "$SOURCE_PATH"/*.dat )` instead of just `file=( *.dat )`?

Comment: Okay, the `\r` says you still didn't fix the problem with DOS newlines. The old question was closed with a link to a duplicate describing how to solve that.

Comment: You can use a tool like `dos2unix`, or you can configure whatever editor you used to write the code to save your file in UNIX format.

Comment: I am writing the script in Unix itself

Comment: Like vi test.sh

Comment: Run `bash -x test.sh` to log execution, and [edit] the log into the question.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your patience. I figured it out. I didn’t find answer tab to post what resolved my issue.

Comment: I created new text document in notepad++ before I write any code in the edit tab went to EOL Conversation and selected as UNIX. Then I started coding. file=(*.dat) and cp “${file[@]}” “$SOURCE_TARGET”.  This two command fixed my issue.

Comment: BTW, in vim, `:set fileformat=unix` will make it save files with LFs even if before that file used CRLFs.

Comment: BTW why not just `cp "$SOURCE_PATH/"*.dat "$SOURCE_TARGET"`  (no need for `cd`, nor `FILE`)

Comment: Yes, will update it accordingly. Thank you. I just had for clear understanding.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sir I don’t know vim. I am using $vi filename to edit the file

Comment: `vim` is "vi improved"; it's a newer alternative to vi with more features, but otherwise works pretty much the same way.